# how get multiple line starting with and format them

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I Have a file which contains multiple lines.I want only few things from that output.Below is the output i am getting from server.

Output:

```
      "az": "nova", 
      "cloud": "envvars", 
      "config_drive": "", 
      "created": "2016-08-19T17:21:24Z", 
      "flavor": {
        "id": "4", 
        "name": "m1.large"
      }, 
      "hostId": "f714baee5967dc17e7d36c7b72eb92a4f1ab68d9782fa90a968ceae5", 
      "human_id": "dsc-test-3", 
      "id": "3f0a1188-c151-4e5e-9930-969d0423601b", 
      "image": {
        "id": "7f4ad1f4-6fab-4978-b65a-ec4b9a407c5c", 
        "name": "mitel-dsc-7.9-9.15_3nic"
      }, 
      "interface_ip": "172.16.17.15", 
      "key_name": "key1", 
      "metadata": {}, 
      "name": "dsc-test-3", 
      "networks": {
        "dsc-InterInstance": [
          "172.16.18.15"
        ], 
        "dsc-OAM": [
          "172.16.16.20"
        ], 
        "dsc-sig": [
          "172.16.17.15", 
          "10.10.72.15"
        ]
      },
```

My intention is to get below things

Required:

```
    "networks": {
    "dsc-InterInstance": [
      "172.16.18.15"
    ], 
    "dsc-OAM": [
      "172.16.16.20"
    ], 
    "dsc-sig": [
      "172.16.17.15", 
      "10.10.72.15"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: If this was a proper JSON you could use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this method

```
sed -n  '/networks.*{/,/}/p' fileName
```

**Outputs:**

```
 "networks": {
    "dsc-InterInstance": [
      "172.16.18.15"
    ], 
    "dsc-OAM": [
      "172.16.16.20"
    ], 
    "dsc-sig": [
      "172.16.17.15", 
      "10.10.72.15"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk solution:

```
awk '/"networks"/,/}/' file.txt
```

This gives the output

```
"networks": {
  "dsc-InterInstance": [
    "172.16.18.15"
  ], 
  "dsc-OAM": [
    "172.16.16.20"
  ], 
  "dsc-sig": [
    "172.16.17.15", 
    "10.10.72.15"
  ]
},
```

The syntax used here is `/start_regex/,/stop_regex/`, which starts matching when a line matches `start_regex` and stops matching after a line matches `stop_regex` (so all the lines in between also get matched). Since no action is specified, the default `{print}` action is used.

Compared to your requirement, this outputs an extra `,` on the last line, since that comma is present in the input. If that is unacceptable, you could get rid of it using the action `{sub("},","}");print}`. Or by using `sed` as in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

... and the tagged `grep` solution as well:

```
$ cat file|tr '\n' _| grep -o \[^_\]*\"networks\"\[^}\]*}|tr _ '\n'
      "networks": {
        "dsc-InterInstance": [
          "172.16.18.15"
        ],
        "dsc-OAM": [
          "172.16.16.20"
        ],
        "dsc-sig": [
          "172.16.17.15",
          "10.10.72.15"
        ]
      }
```

ie. change every `\n` to `_`, `grep` out the requested block and put the `\n` back. `_` may not be the best choice for a substitute but works in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT you can just use a regexp to describe the string you're looking for:

```
$ awk -v RS='"networks": {[^}]+}' 'RT{print RT}' file
"networks": {
        "dsc-InterInstance": [
          "172.16.18.15"
        ],
        "dsc-OAM": [
          "172.16.16.20"
        ],
        "dsc-sig": [
          "172.16.17.15",
          "10.10.72.15"
        ]
      }
```